# Writing articles in wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, posts

First of all to say that I'm new and I do not know many things about coding.
In recent days I have locally installed Wordpress and reviewed the options, but one thing worries me now.
Specifically, I want to open a website with a variety of articles, and I do not know whether to format text using shortcodes, or is it best to just do a visual editing.
I started with shortcodes in functions, but, it seems a bit too much for me as I am alone working on website.
Too many shortcodes somehow confuses me.
I do not know now whether to continue to create shortcodes, or to work with visual editor in plain html.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no definitive answer for this. Use what works best for you, maybe a mix of both. And there are those advanced visual editors sold at codecanyon. Also, check what's on-topic ([help]) on each site before asking (see the footer for a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience short-codes are short-sighted. When you redesign or get rid of shortcodes all your old articles will show them and the designs will be broken.

I think shortcodes are a shortcut you don't want to take if your seriously trying to build content. In the long run they will hurt you.

But, if your just messing around with wordpress or causally blogging, short code away :).

I personally think best practice is to learn HTML, CSS and use that to build interesting content in your articles... Supporting legacy CSS is easier, if you know your creating very specific designs in your article then write the css in the article it-self using `<style>` tag.

That's my opinion at least.

Comment: Yes, you're right, shortcodes can lock the user by theme, I think that I will only use ones that I code in functions.php.